# Can I pass complex objects as inputs to Spring WebFlow Subflows?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

From:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#subflow-state-element-input

I see that I can specify a `type` for flow `input` (and `output`) elements, but I don't see any indication of whether those types can be anything other than simple, single-value types.

If I'm using a Flow as a Subflow, I have some cases where I'd like to pass a POJO or a Map. I'm guessing this is not supported, but want to confirm that before I proceed in trying to make those cases work.

(BTW, I realize I can pass objects by placing them directly on some accessible scope. I'm asking specifically about `input`/`output`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<input name="myObject" type="com.example.MyObject"/>
```

With MyObject being Serializable.

For a map you would have to use an implementation type that is Serializable as well

```
<input name="myObject" type="java.util.HashMap"/>
```

You can map anything you want to your output as well

Comment: That was the hope. I was checking to see whether it actually worked. None of the documentation or examples I've found do this. Do you know first-hand this works? Of course, I can just try it too.

Comment: I have been using this stuff for 4 years, so yes I know first-hand this works :)

Comment: you don't need the type if you are just using it in a subflow, as long as that type is specified in the subflow definition.